# Changing property in MultiBinding doesn't affect the actual object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following scenario:

```
<Setter Property="ItemsSource">
    <Setter.Value>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource itemsSourceConv}" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding Path="DataSource" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}"></Binding>
            <Binding Path="DataSet" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="TwoWay"></Binding>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

I have a dependency property on a control which is binded to some data.
Inside the XAML of the control I have this code which must take the data from the DependancyProperty and pass it to the view model of the control.

I have determined it would be easier for me to do it with Multi Binding.

The problem is that the DataSet property inside the control ViewModel doesn't get set after I execute the converter.

Here's how the MultiBinding converter looks like

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var dataFromWindow = values[0] as List<object>;
    var controlViewModel = values[1];
    controlViewModel = dataFromWindow ; //After execution this object is changed but the object that values[1] references in the viewmodel isn't changed.
    return dataFromWindow;

}
```

Does MultiBinding create a copy of the object I pass it and not work with the reference to it?

EDIT:

Resolved by directly assigning the DataContext.DataSet inside a converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work with the reference. But that's it. You reassign *your* local reference. Nothing more. Your local reference is a copy of the copy of the original reference.

You will need to pass the parent and then set the DataSet property or call a method of the DataSet that does the changes you want.